# Make pagination count selection sticky on the review page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, pagination

Today on Stack Overflow I was blessed because the count on the review page, low quality tab went under 90, so pagination was enabled.  I immediately went to the bottom and selected a post count of 50.  When I went back later today, and it was still under 90, it had defaulted back to 15.

Could we make the pagination post count sticky please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell this has been implemented, along with other `/review` display options such as date range filters and sort order.

I've tested this by selecting the page size (and filter/sort options). This resulted in the following querystring:

```
?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=month&customsort=shortest&no-random=1
```

Then, upon loading `/review` on another machine, all settings were inherited from my other session, and on clicking other tabs the same querystring ispresent ([as long as I avoided the  suggested-edits tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112096/134327)).

That was repeated using different combination of parameters. All behaved as expected.

---

As an aside, `pagesize` can be set to any value between 15 and 1000. Values that are smaller/larger gets reset to the threshold values (15 or 1000). Invalid input resets it to 15.

Comment: So in other words, if the query string contains a pagesize it's sticky? That's rather not what he intended.

Comment: not quite. If you come in fresh to `/review` the options are already set (I've actually counted the entries to make sure it's correct even for odd values such as 42) so the settings are definitely stored off-browser.

Comment: ok, I see where you put that, I thought you meant you loaded something with a querystring. /facepalm to me, +1 to you

Comment: Also, moving between tabs under `/review` reinstates the querysting which is how I managed to visually confirm that the values were inherited by a different session in different browsers

Comment: @jcolebrand it was my bad - I wasn't being very clear. Answer edited.

Comment: Yes, they have fixed it now.