# Some sticky options reset by "suggested-edits" tab

Tags: bug, review

Upon entering the ["suggested edits" tab under `/review`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), previously sticky options for displaying `/review` posts are reset.

Settings for `no-random` and `customsort` is lost, while `filter` is reset to the default `filter=day`. Stickiness of `pagesize` is not affected.

Repro steps:

1. Go to one of the `/review` tabs and choose your filter and sort order (here's a [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=week&customsort=newestfirst&no-random=1)).

   [image: stick in options]
2. Click on the "suggested edits" tab. Options **appear** to be sticky.

   [image: options appear to be sticky]
3. Click back to one of the other tabs. Most options are lost or reset!

   [image: stickiness lost]

This is rather annoying and I find myself avoiding the suggested-edits tab just so I don't have to reinstate my options by scrolling all the way down the page to disable random ordering, then hunt for the custom sort options in the sidebar halfway down the page.

I can bypass this problem by bookmarking one of the tabs with the appropriate querystrings in place, but this shouldn't happen in the first place.

Comment: Sort of related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105030/make-pagination-count-selection-sticky-on-the-review-page

Comment: From what I can tell, pagination post count is already sticky.

Comment: That's what I thought. Maybe that question needs updated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I'm using this amateurishly written UserScript ([RestickSticky](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/119082)) to bypass the issue by adding the current querystring to the tab links so that the settings stick when navigating away from "suggested edits".

However, this will not work if `/review/suggested-edits` is the last tab used. The next time we come back to `/review`, it defaults to the `suggested-edits` tab and previous options are lost. For this situation, I use another another UserScript ([Accessible CustomSort](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/119086)) to make the sort options accessible without unnecessary scrolling.

[image: view with random ordering disable]

[image: view with random ordering enabled]

This does not solve the problem, but it does make it more bearable.

Comment: +1 for drawing freehand with freehand.